# How Rails 3 decides which HTTP verb will be used when clicking on a link generated by "link_to"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, http-verbs, http-method

I have two links:

```
<%= link_to("Edit", edit_product_path(product.id)) %>
<%= link_to("Delete", product, :method => :delete) %>
```

The generated links are:

```
<a href="/products/81/edit">Edit</a>
<a href="/products/81" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

When clicking both on `Edit` and on `Delete`, the `GET` method is used.

How Rails decided which method to use ?

What does `data-method="delete"` and `rel="nofollow"` mean in the `Delete` link ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browsers usually support GET and POST HTTP methods. To emulate PUT and DELETE verbs, Rails injects a special `_method` parameter when a form is submitted.

You specify the method you want to use by passing the `:method` option, as you did.

```
<%= link_to("Action with DELETE", path_to_something, :method => :delete) %>
<%= link_to("Action with PUT", path_to_something, :method => :put) %>
```

Unless specified, the default value is `GET`.

Starting from Rails 3, Rails uses unobtrusive JavaScript to handle the DELETE method. It passes the HTTP verb in the `data-method` attribute, which is an [HTML 5 feature](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

In your case, it doesn't work because you probably forgot to include a JavaScript library (e.g. Prototype or jQuery) and the Rails adapter.

Make sure you are using either jQuery or Prototype, and you are including the `rails.js` javascript file.
Also, don't forget to add the `csrf_meta_tag`.

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

If you want to learn move, I wrote an article about [Unobtrusive JavaScript in Rails 3](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) a few months ago.

Comment: since IE does not expose the data-method attribute does this still work for IE7,8?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  I can confirm that link_to with the ":method => :delete" option does work in the default scaffold.  However, in trying to build a project without scaffolding, I cannot get link_to to work.  button_to works with no problem, using the same parameters that failed with link_to.

In my HEAD tag I have the required javascript includes:

```
javascript_include_tag :defaults
csrf_meta_tag
```

Very confusing.  I couldn't figure out what "secret sauce" scaffolding puts into play to make link_to work. While Rob's assertion that link_to delete does not work in Rails 3, may not be technically accurate, I found it practically accurate.  Thanks Rob, I had been stuck for hours until I saw your post.

Comment: A follow up to my comment - I found that I had some javascript config issues. 1) The rails application builder that I used put my jquery.js file in the "public/javascript" folder, but within a folder call jquery (I had to move it up a level.) 2) the config/application.rb file had two javascript configuration lines. I deleted one and made sure the second one pointed to the jquery.js file mentioned above. With those to changes the link_to with ":method = > :delete"option worked perfectly.  Net, net, if link_to is not showing the :confirm javascript, it's a JS config issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a link for a delete in rails 3
You need to use a button_to eg.

```
<%= button_to("Delete", product, :method => :delete) %>
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can actually use a link. In fact, the default scaffold uses it.